# Implementing Zobrist hashing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, hashtable, v8

I need to implement Zobrist hashing for a chess engine in Javascript and I'm wondering what is the best way of accomplishing this. Now, I'm not a computer scientist and never had formal algorithms and data structures classes so I'm sorry if I'm a bit off on this...

From what I understand I need a 64 bit hashfunction to encode a position as lower than that originates too many collisions. Now in javascript I only have access to 32 bits numbers. Also there is an issue with how I implement the hash table and how it gets implemented "behind the scenes" by the V8 engine in node.

I can either have it as a javascript array of length TABLESIZE and do something like:

```
var table = new Array();

table[hashCodeLo % TABLESIZE] = {
    hashCodeLo: hashCodeLo,
    hashCodeHi: hashCodeHi,
    someProperty: someValue
};
```

where hashCodeLo and hashCodeHi denote the higher and lower 32 bits of the code and TABLESIZE < 2^32. I store these to detect collisions from doing the % TABLESIZE bit. Now I'm guessing since TABLESIZE is large and I'm assigning elements non contiguously V8 will kick this into "dictionary mode" anyways so I might as well not bother making it an array indexed by an integer up to TABLESIZE and instead do something like:

```
var table = {};

table[hashCode] = {
    someProperty: someValue
}
```

where here hashCode is just a string representation of my 64 bits hashCode. Since I'm not sure how "dictionary mode" works behind the scenes I'm not sure which is better. Also I don't know if I'm using more memory by using keys like '1983981918391' vs a more compact representation like:

```
hashCode = String.fromCharCode(FIRST_16BITS, SECOND_16BITS, THIRD_16BITS, FOURTH_16BITS)
```

I'm not even sure if this works the way I intend...

Since this is a critical part of the engine I want to squeeze as much performance as I can out of this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you running v8, with which environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I understand I need a 64 bit hashfunction to encode a position as lower than that originates too many collisions.

Not for the [transposition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_table) at least - it will hardly have a size of 2<sup>64</sup>.

If you're implementing this to encode the positions themselves (and detect some of the collisions by comparing the 64-bit hash), then yes you can use 64 bits if that is what literature recommends (though you might want to try 52 bits as well).

> Now in javascript I only have access to 32 bits numbers.

No. Numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floats, and you can store up to 52-bit integers in them precisely. Only the bitwise operators are limited to 32-bit integers (to whom the numbers will be casted if necessary).

However, arrays themselves are limited to a length of 2<sup>32</sup>; yet even this should be more than enough.

> Also there is an issue with how I implement the hash table and how it gets implemented "behind the scenes" by the V8 engine in node.

Just implement is as an array. Try to fill it with `null` values for initialisation and see whether a non-sparse array performs better. If you care about performance, **test it**.

> hashCodeLo and hashCodeHi denote the higher and lower 32 bits of the code and TABLESIZE < 2^32. I store these to detect collisions

I'd use a [`Uint32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Uint32Array) instead of an array of objects. Depending on what `someProperty` and `someValue` are, you might want to just store an index of an object in a normal array, or a scalar itself (possibly using a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataView)). The code might look like this:

```
var zobrist = new Uint32Array(13 * 2 * 64 * 2) // pieces * colors * fields * 64/32
for (var i=0; i<zobrist.length; i++)
    zobrist[i] = Math.random() * 4294967296;

var table = new Uint32Array(3 * tablesize);

function hash(hi, lo, piece, color, field) {
    hi ^= zobrist[piece * 128 + color * 64 + field];
    lo ^= zobrist[piece * 128 + color * 64 + field + 1];

    var i = lo % tablesize;
    if (table[i] == hi && table[i+1] == lo) {
        // collision
    } else {
        table[i] = hi; table[i+1] = lo;
        // do what you want with table[i+2]
    }
}
```

Comment: >No. How did you come to that conclusion? There are way more than 264 possible chess positions, and you are hardly attempting to store (or even enumerate) them all.

Comment: This seems to be the consensus in the chess literature I read. I know there are a lot more than 2^64 possible chess positions but again I need the key to be 64 bits to detect a reasonable number of collisions.
Storing the full position in the transposition table seems way to wastful and I haven't seen any engine that does it. By reducing this to 64 bits I'm assuming you get a decent compromise between the hash table size and # of collisions that go undetected. I didn't do the math on this, I'm just going by what others have done...

Comment: Ah, I see now that you would use the hashes to encode the actual positions, not just for the transposition table index. I thought a hash table size of 2^64 would've been a bit large…